# How do you show pickerView only while held?

Tags: ios, swift, slider, uipickerview

I'm researching the way to implement a Picker View works like the camera app [Manual](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/manual-custom-exposure-camera/id917146276?mt=8).

[image: That's shutter speed chooser]
[image: Tap and hold...]
[image: And slide then pick]

So, those pickers are shown only while held. Move up and down to choose value, then the value finger left off will be selected.

How would you implement this kind of view, what view would you use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably mask the picker view when it isn't selected to get that appearance

Comment: That sounds nice. What about the slide to pick? That picker in Manual app works just like an UISlider placed vertically. Im assuming that customizing UISlider is the possibility though havent found if that work....